# explain WEC7 virtual/physical address space

Tags: windows-ce, virtual-memory, ndis, windows-embedded-compact, virtual-address-space

Can anyone explain about the address spacing (virtual/physical) in WEC7 (Windows Embedded Compact 7)?

and Virtual to physical address mapping with examples?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Embedded Compact 7's virtual memory model is the same as in CE 6, which is explained in detail here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee483001(v=winembedded.60).aspx

I know of no large difference between 6 and 7 except for the amount of supported physical memory (512MB in 6 vs. 3GB in 7).